# How to cache database data for multiple user roles in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, caching

My server is storing a million survey records, and each user in the system has particular rights to access the data (e.g admin can view all records, requester only views records in his department, and so on).
The goal is that my website shows reports for logged-in users. However when users access the webpage, it really takes time to retrieve correct data from the database because it needs to join multiple tables to get the allowed accessed data for each user role.

I have a plan to cache the data somewhere to reduce the loading time (it means that there will be no need to query data every time users go to the website). The question is that each role has a set of data, how can I cache data efficiently and make them always up-to-date for all user roles?

**Updated: actually the query does not take much time. The thing is I need to process data as PivotTable (using Pandas library), this process really takes time and cost memory because it needs to read whole data. I can cache the result somewhere, when users access the page, server does not need to query and process pivotTable again. But the problem is that new data are always added, I don't know how to keep a cache up-to-date properly

Comment: Check [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html)

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto but I have multiple roles and lots of users in multiple facilities/departments, how can I use MATERIALIZED VIEW to cache the result for each user role?

Comment: You do not cache for each user. The materialized view will cache your unormalized view.

Comment: "a million survey records" should not cause you any troubles. Are your queries optimized?